# What do you call someone who makes a famous saying?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I've heard somebody call the person who says something which becomes well known as the author but it doesn't sound right to me.

Is it correct or is there a better word?

It should be appropriate in the sentence

- The famous saying “Every problem is an opportunity in disguise” is attributed to both John Adams and Benjamin Franklin. If I had to bet on one of them, I would go with Benjamin Franklin as the _______.

And preferably in

- Yes, both of them are ________.

Comment: Do you mean _quoter_?

Comment: Can you please give a sentence with a space for where the candidate should be inserted.

Comment: Well, they’re *famous*.

Comment: A "quoter" is the person who quotes or references something, not the person who says the original thing. Sadly I don't have a better answer.

Comment: Sure @EdwinAshworth.

The famous saying “Every problem is an opportunity in disguise” is attributed to both John Adams and Benjamin Franklin.

If I had to bet on one of them, I would go with Benjamin Franklin as the _______.

Answer (score 3):

Better alternative to my previous answer: **aphorist**

> **Aphorism**
> 2. a terse formulation of a truth or sentiment: ADAGE
>
> Example: the high-minded aphorism, "Let us value the quality of life, not the quantity"

> 3. an ingeniously terse style of expression: aphoristic language
>
> Example: These are dazzling chapters, packed with perfectly chosen anecdotes and pithy with aphorism.
> — John Keegan

[[Merriam-Webster Dictionary]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aphorism)

Comment: And if the saying is "Life was like a box of chocolates. You never know what you’re gonna get." then he's an *aphorist Gump*.